# Getting married in Madrid, looking for affordable group housing for friends & family

Tags: accommodation, rental, spain, group-travel, madrid

I'm an American getting married to a Spanish woman in Madrid, Spain.  I'd like to find some affordable housing for my guests who will be visiting (friends and family) to try and cut down their costs.  Is renting a large apartment or a time share common in Madrid?  Otherwise, can anyone recommend anything?

EDIT/UPDATE: Specified "Madrid" instead of ambiguous "Spain"

Comment: You did not mention a particular city. Can you update your question with the city where you'll be getting married. And Congrats for the wedding :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is common. Sites like [HomeAway](http://www.homeaway.com/vacation-rentals/spain/r58) have thousands of rental listings.

Comment: I'm going to also try airbnb.com ... I'll try to remember and come back here to post an update once the wedding and arrangements are all said and done!

Answer (score 3):

[AirBnB](http://www.airbnb.com/) is one of the faster growing accommodation sites and includes large apartments with multiple bedrooms; depending on the time, and details, you may get something there.

Answer (score 3):

When I visited Barcelona some years back, I came across [Apartments Ramblas](http://www.apartmentsramblas.com/). It is a search engine primarily for apartments in Barcelona. If you change the city to Madrid though, you get suggestions as well. 
The options are self-catering btw.